# org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Unable to parse date from:null

Tags: java, json, ajax, struts

How can I try null value date in my json from ajax to action strus2?

```
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Unable to parse date from: null
```

Comment: What did you try before?

Comment: I was built json from frontend, it is action property type Date but, this content null somethings like that {"birthday" : "null"} and send it through ajax calling action. After that log console show above exception, so, What can I do when this field is empty to built json, wich one is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Can you post some actual code of what you have, and write a bit more detailed on your question? I'm trying to help.